Swift Package manager hangs on infinite spinner
I open swift package manager window in xcode by going file -> Add package dependencies. The window opens but all I get is an infinite spinner when trying to view recently used or when I try to search for a specific package. I have tried:

Resetting the package caches via file -> Packages -> reset package caches
Deleted the caches via the terminal:

rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/org.swift.swiftpm
rm -rf ~/Library/org.swift.swiftpm


Deleting Xcode and reinstalling.

Restarting Xcode.


I'm unsure what else I can do to solve this issue, I currently cannot install new Package dependencies and I really want to avoid going back to cocoapods. Any advice on how to solve this issue would be appreciated.
Specs:

Intel i5 2020 MacBook pro.
macOS sequoia 15.1.1 (24B91)
Xcode Version 16.1 (16B40)

Screenshot of issue:


That's no suppose to be a answer but right now i am able to find issues with every intel processor while new macos(sequoia) released and i only found one solution tried multiple time(ex : 3 to 4 time).

Perhaps GitHub was down temporarily. Try again now.

You might even try deleting your GitHub account from Xcode and reentering it

I’m facing a similar issue. I discovered that the problem arises from having two source control accounts: GitHub and Bitbucket. If I remove Bitbucket, everything works as expected.
As a workaround, you can add the required package to favorites on GitHub, and then you can see it in Xcode in add package dependency...->source control accounts->GitHub

This was the problem. Thank you. I removed bitbucket and the system worked again.
